# Node.jsでGUIプログラムの作成＆RS-232Cとの接続

Tags: node.js

Node.jsでGUIプログラムを構築しようとして、以下のHTMLをnw.exeで起動しました。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>node-webkitを試す</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('package.json', function (err, data) {
if (err) throw err;
document.write(data);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

すると、画面が表示され、package.jsonの内容が表示されます。

ここに、RS-232Cとの接続をしたいので、

```
var SerialPort, serialPort;
SerialPort = require("serialport");
```

の2行を

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

の前に挿入すると、何も表示されなくなります。

恐らく

```
SerialPort = require("serialport");
```

が失敗しているのだと思うのですが、原因が分かりません。

```
serialportは
npm install --save serialport
```

でインストールしました。

何がいけないのでしょうか？

ご教授下さい。

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qiita.com/shinyaYS/items/6149b5a17f920a46879c

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/68657

Comment: 何にしろ、まずは[開発ツール](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Debugging%20with%20DevTools/)で何かエラーメッセージなどが出ていないか確認するのをお勧めします。